# What code do I edit in my .xsl file for RSS Viewer Web Part?

Tags: 2007

I would like to customize my RSS Viewer to scroll vertically and I have my Javascript code to allow it to scroll but I do not know where to place this code.  Where do I put my code in the .xsl file?

Comment: Have you tried adding the code in a separate content editor web part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I would add this as an answer since it would be too big for the comment.
Here is the code for it:

```
Jquery reference needed
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript> var html = ''; $(document).ready(function(){ $.get('feed URL', function(xml){ $("item", xml).each(function(){ $(this).find("link").each(function(){ html += "<a href='" + this.text +"'>"; }).end().find("title").each(function(){ html += this.text + "</a><br />";}).end().find("description").each(function(){ html += "<div>" + this.text +"</div>"; })}); $("#rss").html(html).slideDown("fast");});}); </SCRIPT>
```

```
<.div id="marqueecontainer" onMouseover="copyspeed=pausespeed" onMouseout="copyspeed=marqueespeed">
<.div id="vmarquee" style="position: absolute;">
<.div id="rss" style="width: 190px; border:0px">Loading...<./div><./div><./div>
```

I added .'s to the HTML to show up and it is all one line to be minimized.  You just need to change the 'feed URL' and it should work.